# How to capture value from attribute

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have simple structure of XML file like this:

```
  <Employee>
    <EmpId>1</EmpId>
    <Name>Sam</Name>
    <Sex>Male</Sex>
    <Phone Type="Home">423-555-0124</Phone>
    <Phone Type="Work">424-555-0545</Phone>
    <Address>
      <Street>7A Cox Street</Street>
      <City>Acampo</City>
      <State>CA</State>
      <Zip>95220</Zip>
      <Country>USA</Country>
    </Address>
  </Employee>
```

and many more `Employees` in that XML file.

I want to select only two values: `Name` and `Phone` with attribute `Type = Home`

```
var query = from nm in xElement.Elements("Employee")
            orderby nm.Element("EmpId") descending
            select new 
            {
              Name = nm.Element("Name").Value,
              work_phone = ((string)nm.Element("Phone").Attribute("Type") == "Home").ToString().Single()
        };
```

but it doesn't work. Problem is in `work_phone` (exception about `IComparable`). How can I get this value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
work_phone = (string)nm.Elements("Phone")
                       .FirstOrDefault(o => (string)o.Attribute("Type") == "Home");
```

Another problem is in the `orderby` clause. Try to cast `<EmpId>` value to `int` to make it comparable :

```
.....
orderby (int)nm.Element("EmpId") descending
.....
```

Comment: it doesnt work, similar exception: object must be implement elemement IComparable. (when i cause in foreach)

Comment: that seems to be a problem in your `orderby` clause. Maybe you can try to cast the element for ordering to `int` : `orderby (int)nm.Element("EmpId") descending`

Answer (score 2):

Here is the two selected value:

```
var query = from nm in xElement.Elements("Employee")
                        orderby nm.Element("EmpId") descending
                        select new
                        {
                            Name = nm.Element("Name").Value,
                            HomePhone = (string)nm.Elements("Phone").SingleOrDefault(y => (string)y.Attribute("Type") == "Home")
                        };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = from nm in xElement.Elements("Employee")
            orderby (int)nm.Element("EmpId") descending
            select new
            {
                Name = nm.Element("Name").Value,
                work_phone = nm.Elements("Phone").First(p=>p.Attribute("Type").Value=="Home").Value
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

As documented here :- http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=564

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Load("..\\..\\Employees.xml");

var homePhone = from phoneno in xelement.Elements("Employee")

                where (string)phoneno.Element("Phone").Attribute("Type") == "Home"

                select phoneno;

Console.WriteLine("List HomePhone Nos.");

foreach (XElement xEle in homePhone)

{

    Console.WriteLine(xEle.Element("Phone").Value);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

```
var xml_data = "<Employee> <EmpId>1</EmpId> <Name>Sam</Name> <Sex>Male</Sex> <Phone Type=\"Home\">423-555-0124</Phone> <Phone Type=\"Work\">424-555-0545</Phone> <Address> <Street>7A Cox Street</Street> <City>Acampo</City> <State>CA</State> <Zip>95220</Zip> <Country>USA</Country> </Address> </Employee>";
            var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml_data);

            var result = xdoc.Elements("Employee").
                Where((x) =>
                    {
                        var home_phones = x.Elements("Phone").Where(y => (string)y.Attribute("Type") == "Home").ToList();
                        return home_phones.Count > 0;
                    }).
                ToList();
```